# Why does a different method in slicing a 2d array give me an extra set of brackets?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
>>> practice
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 2, 5, 3, 5],
       [8, 5, 7, 9, 4]])

>>> practice[:1,] # extra set of brackets when taking out the 1st row
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

>>> practice[0, :] # one set of brackets when taking out the 1st row
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I'm new to arrays and cannot figure out why I'm getting an extra set of brackets when I index using a slice. When I index using an integer, the solution only has one set of brackets. Even though I am getting the same numbers, is my method wrong?

I followed the `[start:stop]` method that I was taught, but the solution appears to do things a bit differently.

Comment: No screenshots of text please. You should paste the text instead, and [format it using a code block](/help/formatting)

Comment: I removed your screenshot and replaced it with the text. I didn't transcribe the second example because it's redundant

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The 'extra set of brackets' has meaning; it isn't just decoration.  Look at the shape of the result, and compare it to the original.  The different ways of indexing is documented, so you shouldn't have to puzzle (too much) over the whys.  Or worry about right or wrong.  Even with a list indexing with a slice is different `[1,2,3][:1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is that in the first case, you are [using a slice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding), whereas in the second you are [indexing a single element](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing)

With single-element indexing, numpy knows for sure that there can only be one row returned, so it implicitly [squeezes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) the result and returns the row as a 1-dimensional array of shape `(5,)`

On the other hand, slicing *can* (and usually is) used to return more than a single row. To maintain generality, numpy keeps both dimensions, and returns an array of shape `(1, 5)`.